# Extraction of registration number of a car

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

Please help me out the number of a car. Robbers entered our city late at night to steal in 3 cars including my car. High value coins and other items were taken away. The neighbor's camera filmed the robbers' vehicle. See picture. Help me from this image to extract the serial number of the vehicle. I am stuck. Thank you.

Video Link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuJnCQ0iIpbo7_YTbHvEF1mqvY71xsqh/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems highly unlikely anyone could pull a plate number out of these stills

Comment: welcome to photo.stackexchange. The images are very bad in quality and its very hard and possibly impossible to extract any data from it. Also I don't know if this is the correct page for these types of image. And the tags have nothing to do with the things you need.

Comment: I think this site isn't the correct place to ask about extracting the registration number out of the poor quality pictures. It's probably impossible. If you want to know what features to look for in a surveillance camera so that the next time your car is stolen you (or your neighbor) can have better quality pictures, this site might be the correct place to ask such a question.

Comment: @juhist *"the next time your car is stolen"*, boy, you're a pessimist :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because PSE isn't a detective agency and not a substitute for your friendly local police department, assuming that the stated context is true and not a ploy.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply @Luciano and colleague. I post here the link of the video for to better enlighten. Because the first picture was only pictures taken with my phone. I cut the video between the entrance of the robber's vehicle and the exit.
   
Vidéo link:  
 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuJnCQ0iIpbo7_YTbHvEF1mqvY71xsqh/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Voting to leave this question closed after the addition of the video link. You need to get any evidence to your police department and hire a professional service to do any evidence digging (the kind that could go up on the stand as a professional witness). This just isn't the place for this.

Comment: @Hueco all country are not same. our police do not have the means for such an investigation. if that were the case I would be on the first day at the police. if I also had the means I will contact an expert on the subject.  To say if I came in this forum is that I need help. It does not just happen to others. I thank all those who helped. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I just need help, not the attacks from those who have to help me. If I could I would already go to the police.

Comment: It's not an attack on you or your topic to say that it's not a fit for this site's format. There are a lot of photography and graphic design forums out there - each has topicality rules. This site does not recommend services (we can't tell you where to go to find a pro) and we wish to have questions that "teach a man to fish" instead of fish for him. You are asking for a salmon dinner here - something that's also off topic.

Comment: I hope you stick around and become a part of the community here - I hope you have further questions related to learning photography. Unfortunately, this just isn't the place for your request - and if I knew a place, then I'd point you to it...but I don't.

Answer (score 3):

Those images are not useful since you took them of some screen.  Instead you need to get at a digital version of the original footage that has not been rerouted through some display device.  Once you have the proper form of footage, for a still photograph the usual remedy is to take a crop of just the license plate area without border, then potentially use some amount of digital filtering followed by histogram equalization.  If that does not work, there are additional techniques for integrating the information of a motion picture across several frames.

The footage likely wants to be processed by experts.

Comment: This is the link of the original video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuJnCQ0iIpbo7_YTbHvEF1mqvY71xsqh/view?usp=drivesdk